# AngularJS custom directive, cant access ngModel on DOM load

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm using Laravel5 and creating a custom directive for angular novalidation forms. Now I can't access ngmodel placed data. My goal is to first show person's name, and then save his name, but name is not showing at DOM load...
Main problem I found is on $watch, but I don't know what to change in it.

Here's my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwPLeg)

**AngularJS code:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', mainController)
    .directive('myInput', myInput);

  function mainController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = {
      email: 'test@tesst.com',
      name: 'Nickelson'
    };
  }

  function myInput() {

    function tempFunc(element, attrs) {
      var templateWithVars = '<input type="inputType" ng-model="fieldModelName" name="fieldModelName" ng-required="required"/>';

      var template = templateWithVars
        .replace("inputType", attrs.type)
        .replace("exampleName", attrs.example)
        .replace(/fieldModelName/g, getFieldModelName(attrs));
      return template;
    }

    function getFieldModelName(attrs) {
      var objectAndField = attrs.ngModel;
      var names = objectAndField.split('.');
      var fieldModelName = names.pop();
      return fieldModelName;
    }

    return {
      replace: false,
      scope: {},
      template: tempFunc,
      require: ['^form', "ngModel"],
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        scope.form = ctrls[0];
        var ngModel = ctrls[1]; // This part is null

        var model = getFieldModelName(attrs);
        scope.$watch(model, function (newVal, oldVal) {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(scope[model]);
        });
      }
    }
  } 
})();
```

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
   <br />
   email: {{ vm.data.email }}
  <br />
   name: {{ vm.data.name }} // Nothing showing in here!!!
  <br />
 <h2>Edit</h2>
  <form novalidation name="vm.form">
    <my-input ng-model="vm.data.name"
            type="text"
            example="vm.data.name">  // My Input by default is empty
    </my-input>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" ng-show="vm.form.$valid" value="Save Name"/> 
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can access the ng-model by calling the value assigned to that ng-model. For example rather than calling attrs.ngModel, you can simply call vm.data.name. Not really sure what you are trying to do but hopefully that helps a little bit.

Comment: I have to make my directive flexible, so I need access ngModel from attrs.
Then page is loaded section [ name: ] is empty, but by default there must be a data from {{ vm.data.name }}, also inside custom directive must have  a filled data to, because I'm giving to him ng-model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the ng-model to your directive in a funky way. It's making it such that it *does* work, but the way it initializes actually overwrites the original ng-model with the blank input.

If you change your $watch function to :

```
if (scope[model] !== undefined) ngModel.$setViewValue(scope[model]);
```

It'll only update the ngModel if it's not undefined, which it is initially.

[Here's an updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obgaPj?editors=101).

Note that you'll actually have to make changes to the input before ngModel is defined (even if you just type a space and backspace, it'll be fine).

Comment: Oh, that help me, but not acually. I got one more thing - then DOM loads, load inside custom Input a value, which is inside vm.data.name. I was trying insert it by ng-model.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but try just adding an `else` statement and assigning `scope[model]` the original value.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem. I don't exacly needed place ngmodel from require: ["ngModel"], but just add it in scope (scope: { ngModel: '=' }), and after that I add it strate to tempFunc, like:

> var templateWithVars = 'input type="inputType" ng-model="ngModel" name="fieldModelName" ng-required="required"/>';

And It kind of fix it...